# Why is my SMB mount using credentials from a different fstab entry

Tags: mount, smbclient

I'm seeing a strange behavior on my Linux server.
I have 2 different SMB shares in my fstab:

```
//192.168.x.x/Share1    /home/user/mnt1   cifs    credentials=/etc/credential_1,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.x.x/Share2    /home/user/mnt2   cifs    credentials=/etc/credential_2,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Now my problem is that if I mount with
`mount -a` or `mount.cifs`, the first mountpoint is mounted correctly, but the second is mounted using the credential present in the file `/etc/credential_1` instead of using `/etc/credential_2`.

Could someone explain me why this is and how to fix it?